# Django migrations no changes detected when mixin added

Tags: django

I am trying add a `CommentModelMixin` to an existing model but the changes are not being picked up by django when running `makemigrations`. Instead I get `no changes detected`. If I add a field to the same model changes are detected and migration files are created.

Should django pick up adding mixins to existing models in `makemigrations`?

Edit: add mixin per comment

```
class CommentModel(FullModelMixin, FullManagerMixin):
    comment = models.TextField()
    thread = models.ForeignKey('ops.CommentModel', null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    instance_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'instance_pk')

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.comment) > 10:
            return self.comment[:10] + '...'
        return self.comment

class CommentModelMixin(models.Model):

    comments = GenericRelation(
        CommentModel,
        object_id_field='instance_pk'
    )
    def add_comment(self, comment, thread=None):
        comm = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
        CommentModel.objects.create(
            instance_pk=self.pk,
            content_type=comm, comment=comment, thread=thread
        )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Please provide your CommntModelMixin. Hint: It should inherit from ``models.Model`` and have a ``Meta.abstract = True``

Comment: @Serafeim it does, added mixin. I know the mixin works because I have it in other models but I haven't added it into a model that already existed

Comment: What file is it in? I can't remember if Django is like this but sometimes alembic/sqlalchemy will miss these when making migrations because it's in some random file that's not imported anywhere yet.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist interesting. I am importing `CommentModelMixin` from another app's models

Comment: One which is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?